# how to create horizontally scrollable vertical listview in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

i want to create a list view on Flutter which can be scrolled vertically as well as horizontally.

Like in android we can build a recycler view over a horizontal scroll view then it allows us to scroll vertically as well as horizontally.

Is there any solution for Flutter to behave same.

I have tried nestedScroll view, customscroll view, nested Listview and was not able to achieve what i wanted.

If list view cannot do this please suggest any other widget with this property.

Please anybody help me with the solution. Thanks in advance☺

Comment: check https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/horizontal-list

Comment: this will allow me to create a horizontal list, i do not want that. i want that vertical list  can also be scrolled horizontally, i mean same list view scrollable in both direction. if not list view then any other widget which has this property will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **Data Table** widget.

Two dimensional scrolling is supported by flutter using this widget

Demo using **Flutter Gallery App**[image: Demo]

Comment: thanks for the solution, this is what i exactly wanted. I will try this thank you☺

Comment: Sadly, the Datatables don't support variable cell height list a list. Whomp, whomp.
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/70510